# Create dataframe showing proportions of sliced frame against larger frame

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, pivot-table

I have a data set with 5 years of data.  I would like to create a dataframe that determines the proportion of rows that meet a condition (i.e., Column 1 value > 10) for each County, and how important each county is in the data set (i.e., number of rows).  I would like to determine that separately for each year, so the results can be average by year.  I've accomplished in the code below that for one year of data:

```
df_2018_1 = df[(df.Year=='2018')]
df_2018_2 = df[(df.column_1 > 10) & (df.Year=='2018')]
df_2018_cur = pd.DataFrame()
df_2018_cur['Column 1 > 10'] = df_2018_2.County.value_counts()/df_2018_1.County.value_counts()*100
# Percent of submissions by county out of all submissions (county importance).
df_2018_cur['PCT of State'] = df_2018_1.County.value_counts()/len(df_2018_1)*100

# Repeat for remaining years, then average across dataframes.
```

I would love an alternative strategy with more concise code if possible.  I don't believe that `pivot_table()` supports a `value_counts()` function.  I'm wondering if `groupby` might be useful here, but if so it has not occurred to me just how it would be.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df['Column1_gt_10'] = df['column_1'] > 10
grouped = df.groupby(['Year', 'County'])
aggregated = grouped.agg(
    Column1_gt_10_pct = ('Column1_gt_10', lambda x: x.mean() * 100), 
    County_count = ('Column1_gt_10', 'size')
total_counts_by_year = df.groupby('Year')['County'].count()
aggregated['PCT_of_State'] = aggregated['County_count'] / aggregated.index.get_level_values('Year').map(total_counts_by_year) * 100
final_result = aggregated.groupby(level='County').mean()
```

As per my understanding of the question

1. Grouped by `Year` and `County`
2. Applied the condition of `column_1>10` for each group
3. Get average across year, but before that calculated proportion on county level.

Comment: Excellent, thank you!  This sheds much light on the proper use of groupby.  I only had to make a small change by adding an `.astype("int64")` after the map function to calculate `aggregated['PCT_of_State']`.  Very nice.